# Is it possible to enter an objective-C for loop as an LLDB expression?

Tags: objective-c, lldb

I've seen passing statements that you can enter complex statements like a for loop in an LLDB command (in the language of the program you're debugging - in this case Objective-C)

I would really like to be able to do this. I've never learned Python, and would prefer not to invest the time to do so in order to use the available python LLDB support - there just aren't enough hours in the day for that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can enter Objective-C statements using `expr -- ...`, for example:

```
(lldb) po myArray

(
foo,
bar
)

(lldb) expr -- for (NSString *s in myArray) { (void)NSLog(@"%@", s) ; }

2013-12-03 18:29:03.637 myapp[1373:70b] foo
2013-12-03 18:29:03.639 myapp[1373:70b] bar
```

Comment: Or, more simply, you can just say

(lldb) expr <ENTER>

and you will be able to type as many lines of code as you like. To end, make an empty line and press <ENTER> again. LLDB will then proceed to evaluate whatever chunk of code you typed.

I am not sure, however, that this is a general alternative to the Python support. The two features (expression parser and scripting) have different rationales and use cases, and yes in some cases it’s up to you what to use, but in others it is much more obvious to use one or the other. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I can't get it to work. I tried the simple statement expr -- (void) for (int x = 0;x<5;x++){printf("x = %d\n", x);} as a test, and it says "error: Expected expression". I've also tried prefixing x with a "$", but no luck.

Comment: ok, with some more tinkering I'm finally getting it to work. I needed a void cast on my statement inside the loop. Here is the code I got working:

    expr for (int x = 0; x< 5; x++) {(void) printf("x = %d\n", x);}

Why does the printf need a void cast, but the for loop does not? The (complex) statement that I'm running is the for loop. I would think IT would need the void cast, not the printf.

Comment: @DuncanC: lldb has to know the return type of printf. Compare also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339493/why-cant-lldb-evaluate-this-expression, and in particular Jim Ingham's answer about lldb and functions with variable argument lists.

Comment: (in other news, printf returns an int :-)

Comment: @Enrico, right now I am skill-building with the lldb command line. In the past I've needed to enter a compound statement like a loop and have not been able to figure out how to do so. Adding a void cast (or I guess an int cast) to printf did the trick in my case, but I'm still not clear on when casts are needed and when not.

Comment: @DuncanC `expr -- for (int x = 0;x<5;x++) printf("x = %d\n", x);` works for me. Note the lack of void cast for the for **statement**. Casts should only be needed when an expression type cannot be determined by lldb (eg: some objc message passing)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @"Martin R"'s answer.

At least `NSLog` doesn't seem to print something with Xcode 6.0.1.

```
(lldb) expr -- for(UIWindow *w in [(UIApplication *)[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) { (int)printf("%s\n\n", [(NSString *)[w recursiveDescription] UTF8String]); }
```