# C struct - lldb expression fails

Tags: debugging, lldb

Why can't lldb's `expression` understand my C Struct unless I declare a default variable?

```
struct YD_MENU {
    char menu_name[10];
    int menu_option;
};

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

Adding a breakpoint inside of main...

```
(lldb) exp struct YD_MENU $b
error: variable has incomplete type 'struct YD_MENU'
forward declaration of 'YD_MENU'
```

If I change it to the following...

```
struct YD_MENU {
    char menu_name[10];
    int menu_option;
} default_menu;
```

`(lldb) exp struct YD_MENU $a` works fine.

I think this is related to [Why can't LLDB evaluate this expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339493/why-cant-lldb-evaluate-this-expression) but the proposed answers don't work.

```
(lldb) version
lldb-1000.0.29
```

Answer (score 3):

clang (and gcc as well) are fairly aggressive about not emitting type information for "unused types".  There are so many types floating around when you do something like `import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` that it has to do this to keep debug information size reasonable.  That's why when you define a structure but don't use it, lldb can't see the type.  The information about the type is in fact not there for lldb to see.